# Java drawing a circle using awt,JFrame with Thread(Runnable) on Netbeans (Mac)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

https://github.com/terryaa/KOSTA_MAC/tree/master/Java/NetBeans/day13_01_15/src/ex1

What I'm trying to do is to draw circles, but one circle on a canvas at a time and then moving on to drawing next circle using Runnable join. It should draw a circle using .start() and the other .start() shouldn't start until formal .start()'s drawing circle is done.

In linked page's package, Ex3_Canvas1 class has main and use Runnable MyThread0 class to draw a circle using basic .start() and .join() and it does perfectly what I want.

I created NetBean's automatic JFrame class Ex2_CanvasDemo and tried to do the same and failed. JFrame window pops up after drawing a full circle and then shows creating of next circle. What I want is that the window should first appear and it shows creation of both circles  ,not simulataneously but sequently, like Ex3_Canvas1.

I guess it's because main thread waits for th(Ex2_CanvasDemo) to finish so window doesn't apply for changes. But shouldn't Ex1_Canvas1 should do the same? Is this differences due to automatically generated code by netbeans? How can I do the same as Ex1_Canvas1 in Ex2_CanvasDemo.

I tried making a Runnable class and used in Ex2_CanvasDemo but failed also..

Any help?
I'm using jdk 8 and netbeans8 on mac.

--Thread part of Ex2_CanvasDemo--

```
public Ex2_CanvasDemo() {
                initComponents();
                Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=0;i<370;i+=10){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Ex2_CanvasDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        arcNUm=i;
                        System.out.println("circle"+arcNUm);
                        canvas1.repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
            th.start();
        try {
            th.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ex2_CanvasDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            th=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=0;i<370;i+=10){
                        System.out.println("circle"+i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Ex2_CanvasDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        arcNum2=i;
                        canvas2.repaint();
                    }

                }
            });
            th.start();
//        try {
//            th.join();
//        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(Ex2_CanvasDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        }


    }
```

Comment: Beware [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html); A better solution might revolve around [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: `th.join()` is probably blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing anything from getting painted - see my previous comment

Comment: I'm no expert so I'm not sure I understand the document fully. So you are saying that th.start() also invokes other thread(Event Dispatching Thread) that draws circle but th.join holds them? so Ex3_Canvas1 is not using swing, and that's what's making it work and not mine?                    is there any way to use runnable to make this work..? this was an assignment.. and I'm dead stuck

Comment: Since Thread#join is blocks until the underlying thread it’s wait on finishes, join will block the currently running thread - which happens to be the Event Dispatching Thread and since Swing is not thread safe, you shouldn’t be updating the ui out side of the edt context anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Caveat

Animation is hard, good animation is really hard.  You need to repeat this to yourself, because animation done right is, really hard.

## What you need to know...

Animation is basically the illusion of change over time.  Very rarely do you want to perform linear animation, animation is normally done over a period of time, as it allows for performance difference in the platform to be smoothed out in away which is not as harsh to the user.

Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  This means that you should not block the event dispatching thread and that you must only update the UI from within the context of the event dispatching thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

This makes life a little difficult, as you can't simply run a linear loop in the EDT, as this will block the UI and it's difficult to do it from a `Thread` because it's a mess of synchronisation.

One of the simplest solutions is to make use of the available API and use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which acts as a pseudo loop, putting in a small delay between call backs, in which you can perform some operations

## Example...

While there are a number of ways you might approach this, I've set up a simple `List` which contains a bunch of `Animatable`s which "do stuff" and then simply run one after the other in serial.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane testPane = new TestPane();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(testPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        testPane.play();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Animatable> animations;
        private Animatable animation;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            animations = new ArrayList<>(25);
            animations.add(new CircleAnimation(Color.RED));
            animations.add(new CircleAnimation(Color.BLUE));

            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (animation == null) {
                        animation = animations.remove(0);
                    }
                    if (animation.update(getBounds())) {
                        if (animations.isEmpty()) {
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        } else {
                            animation = animations.remove(0);
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void play() {
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (animation != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                animation.paint(g2d);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    public interface Animatable {
        public boolean update(Rectangle bounds);
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d);
    }

    public class CircleAnimation implements Animatable {
        private Color color;
        private Ellipse2D circle;
        private double delta = -1;

        public CircleAnimation(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle bounds) {
            if (circle == null) {
                circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(bounds.width, (bounds.height / 2) - 10, 20, 20);
            }
            Rectangle rect = circle.getBounds();
            rect.x += delta;
            circle.setFrame(rect);
            return rect.x + 20 < bounds.x;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            if (circle == null) {
                return;
            }
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fill(circle);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This has been so much help. !